# QuickBooks Webconnector Error - Django Soap Web Service - Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call

Tags: django, quickbooks, soaplib, qbwc

I have written a SOAP Web service in django and i have installed the following components

1. soaplib-0.8.1 in my system
2. Quickbooks Pro
3. QBWC version 2.1.0.30 - Intuit

When i try to add an application(.qwc file) to QBWC(Quick Books Web Connector), it is calling my web service. It is giving me the below error

**Error:**
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'Quick Books Integration' has STARTED
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ******************** Update session locked ********************
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: Cognam Technologies Pvt Ltd Quick Books Integration
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): Quick Books Integration
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: http://**test**:8000/qwc/qwcintegration/service.wsdl
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: . For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: . For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'Quick Books Integration', username = 'anil'
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20130807.09:03:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.

The url for Webservice contains localhost instead of test.When posting the issue, it didnt allow me to provide a link with localhost , i changed it to test. Actual link in qwc file contains localhost and not test.

Please help me out.
I guess the SOAP version that QBWC is using and which i have installed are not compatible

I really dont know where i am going wrong. Please help me out to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Code is below:
**views.py**

from soaplib_handler import Array, String, Integer
from soaplib import soap
from soaplib.service import soapmethod
from soaplib_handler import DjangoSoapApp, soapmethod, soap_types

class QuickBooksService(DjangoSoapApp):

```
__tns__ = 'http://developer.intuit.com/'

@soapmethod(soap_types.String, _returns=soap_types.String)
def serverVersion(self, ticket):
    print 'serverVersion()'
    print ticket
    return '2.1'

@soapmethod(soap_types.String,
            soap_types.String,
            _returns=Array(String),
            _outMessage='{http://developer.intuit.com/}authenticateResponse',
            _outVariableName='authenticateResult',
            )
def authenticate(self, strUserName, strPassword):
    print 'authenticate()'
    results = []
    results.append('{85B41BEE-5CD9-427a-A61B-83964F1EB426}')
    results.append('')
    results.append('')

    print strUserName
    print strPassword
    print results
    return results

@soapmethod(soap_types.String, _returns=soap_types.String)
def clientVersion(self, strVersion):
    print 'clientVersion()'
    print strVersion
    return ""

@soapmethod(soap_types.String, _returns=soap_types.String)
def closeConnection(self, ticket):
    print 'closeConnection()'
    print ticket
    return 'closeConnection() called on WS'

@soapmethod(soap_types.String,
            soap_types.String,
            soap_types.String,
            _returns=soap_types.String)
def connectionError(self, ticket, hresult, message):
    print 'connectionError'
    print ticket
    print hresult
    print message
    return 'done'

@soapmethod(soap_types.String, _returns=soap_types.String)
def getLastError(self, ticket):
    print 'lastError()'
    print ticket
    return 'Problems foo bar'

@soapmethod(soap_types.String,
            soap_types.String,
            soap_types.String,
            soap_types.String,
            _returns=Integer,
            _outMessage='{http://developer.intuit.com/}receiveResponseXMLResponse',
            _outVariableName='receiveResponseXMLResult',)
def receiveResponseXML(self, ticket, response, hresult, message):
    print 'receiveResponseXML()'
    print "ticket=" + ticket
    print "response=" + response
    if hresult:
        print "hresult=" + hresult
        print "message=" + message
    return 100

@soapmethod(soap_types.String,
            soap_types.String,
            soap_types.String,
            soap_types.String,
            soap_types.Integer,
            soap_types.Integer,
            _returns=String,
            _outMessage='{http://developer.intuit.com/}sendRequestXMLResponse',
            _outVariableName='sendRequestXMLResult',)
def sendRequestXML(self, ticket, strHCPResponse, strCompanyFileName, qbXMLCountry, qbXMLMajorVers, qbXMLMinorVers ):
    print 'sendRequestXML()'
    print strHCPResponse
    xml =   "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>" + \
            "<?qbxml version=\"2.0\"?>" + \
                "<QBXML>" + \
                    "<QBXMLMsgsRq onError=\"stopOnError\">" + \
                    "<ItemQueryRq></ItemQueryRq>" + \
                "</QBXMLMsgsRq>" + \
            "</QBXML>"
    return xml


@soapmethod(soap_types.String,
            soap_types.String,
            _returns=soap_types.String)
def interactiveUrl(self, ticket, sessionID):
    print 'interactiveUrl'
    print ticket
    print sessionID
    return 'http://localhost/test'


@soapmethod(soap_types.String, _returns=soap_types.String)
def interactiveDone(self, ticket):
    print 'interactiveDone()'
    print ticket
    return 'Done'

@soapmethod(soap_types.String,
            soap_types.String,
            _returns=soap_types.String)
def interactiveRejected(self, ticket, reason):
    print 'interactiveRejected()'
    print ticket
    print reason
    return 'Message to show'
```

quickbooks_service = QuickBooksService()

**Soaplib_handler.py**

from django.http import HttpResponse
from soaplib.serializers import primitive as soap_types
from soaplib.serializers.primitive import _element_to_unicode, Null, _element_to_integer
from soaplib.service import soapmethod
from soaplib.wsgi_soap import SimpleWSGISoapApp

class DjangoSoapApp(SimpleWSGISoapApp):

```
def __call__(self, request):
    print "inside call method"
    django_response = HttpResponse()
    def start_response(status, headers):
        print "initial"
        print status
        print headers
        status, reason = status.split(' ', 1)
        # try:
        #     status, reason = status.split(' ', 1)
        # except:
        #     status = status.split(' ')
        #     reason = ''

        print "status"
        print status
        # s1 = status[0]
        django_response.status_code = int(status)
        for header, value in headers:
            django_response[header] = value

    print "Over"

    response = super(DjangoSoapApp, self).__call__(request.META, start_response)
    django_response.content = "\n".join(response)

    return django_response
```

**urls.py**

urlpatterns = patterns('',

```
url(r'^hello_world/', views.quickbooks_service, name='service'),
url(r'^hello_world/service.wsdl', views.quickbooks_service, name='service2'),
```

)

**Soap Response when i hit the browser:**
----------------------------------------->

```
<definitions xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:tns="http://developer.intuit.com/" xmlns:typens="http://developer.intuit.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://developer.intuit.com/" name="QuickBooksService">
<types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://developer.intuit.com/">
<xs:element name="interactiveUrlResponse" type="tns:interactiveUrlResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="connectionError">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ticket" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="hresult" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="message" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getLastErrorResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="getLastErrorResult" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="interactiveRejected">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ticket" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="reason" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="clientVersion" type="tns:clientVersion"/>
<xs:element name="receiveResponseXML" type="tns:receiveResponseXML"/>
<xs:complexType name="interactiveRejectedResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="interactiveRejectedResult" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="interactiveRejectedResponse" type="tns:interactiveRejectedResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="connectionErrorResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="connectionErrorResult" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="getLastErrorResponse" type="tns:getLastErrorResponse"/>
<xs:element name="interactiveRejected" type="tns:interactiveRejected"/>
<xs:complexType name="getLastError">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ticket" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="authenticate">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="strUserName" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="strPassword" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="clientVersion">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="strVersion" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="interactiveUrl" type="tns:interactiveUrl"/>
<xs:complexType name="interactiveUrlResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="interactiveUrlResult" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="connectionError" type="tns:connectionError"/>
<xs:element name="getLastError" type="tns:getLastError"/>
<xs:element name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}sendRequestXMLResponse" type="tns:{http://developer.intuit.com/}sendRequestXMLResponse"/>
<xs:element name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}authenticateResponse" type="tns:{http://developer.intuit.com/}authenticateResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="interactiveDone">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ticket" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="serverVersion">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ticket" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="connectionErrorResponse" type="tns:connectionErrorResponse"/>
<xs:element name="sendRequestXML" type="tns:sendRequestXML"/>
<xs:element name="authenticate" type="tns:authenticate"/>
<xs:element name="closeConnectionResponse" type="tns:closeConnectionResponse"/>
<xs:element name="interactiveDone" type="tns:interactiveDone"/>
<xs:element name="serverVersionResponse" type="tns:serverVersionResponse"/>
<xs:element name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}receiveResponseXMLResponse" type="tns:{http://developer.intuit.com/}receiveResponseXMLResponse"/>
<xs:element name="serverVersion" type="tns:serverVersion"/>
<xs:complexType name="interactiveUrl">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ticket" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="sessionID" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="stringArray">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:string" name="string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="interactiveDoneResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="interactiveDoneResult" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="receiveResponseXML">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ticket" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="response" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="hresult" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="message" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="sendRequestXML">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ticket" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="strHCPResponse" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="strCompanyFileName" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="qbXMLCountry" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="qbXMLMajorVers" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="qbXMLMinorVers" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="closeConnectionResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="closeConnectionResult" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}receiveResponseXMLResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="receiveResponseXMLResult" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}sendRequestXMLResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="sendRequestXMLResult" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="serverVersionResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="serverVersionResult" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="interactiveDoneResponse" type="tns:interactiveDoneResponse"/>
<xs:element name="closeConnection" type="tns:closeConnection"/>
<xs:complexType name="closeConnection">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ticket" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="stringArray" type="tns:stringArray"/>
<xs:element name="clientVersionResponse" type="tns:clientVersionResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="clientVersionResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="clientVersionResult" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}authenticateResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="authenticateResult" type="tns:stringArray"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</schema>
</types>
<message name="authenticate">
<part name="authenticate" element="tns:authenticate"/>
</message>
<message name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}authenticateResponse">
<part name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}authenticateResponse" element="tns:{http://developer.intuit.com/}authenticateResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="clientVersion">
<part name="clientVersion" element="tns:clientVersion"/>
</message>
<message name="clientVersionResponse">
<part name="clientVersionResponse" element="tns:clientVersionResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="closeConnection">
<part name="closeConnection" element="tns:closeConnection"/>
</message>
<message name="closeConnectionResponse">
<part name="closeConnectionResponse" element="tns:closeConnectionResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="connectionError">
<part name="connectionError" element="tns:connectionError"/>
</message>
<message name="connectionErrorResponse">
<part name="connectionErrorResponse" element="tns:connectionErrorResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="getLastError">
<part name="getLastError" element="tns:getLastError"/>
</message>
<message name="getLastErrorResponse">
<part name="getLastErrorResponse" element="tns:getLastErrorResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="interactiveDone">
<part name="interactiveDone" element="tns:interactiveDone"/>
</message>
<message name="interactiveDoneResponse">
<part name="interactiveDoneResponse" element="tns:interactiveDoneResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="interactiveRejected">
<part name="interactiveRejected" element="tns:interactiveRejected"/>
</message>
<message name="interactiveRejectedResponse">
<part name="interactiveRejectedResponse" element="tns:interactiveRejectedResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="interactiveUrl">
<part name="interactiveUrl" element="tns:interactiveUrl"/>
</message>
<message name="interactiveUrlResponse">
<part name="interactiveUrlResponse" element="tns:interactiveUrlResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="receiveResponseXML">
<part name="receiveResponseXML" element="tns:receiveResponseXML"/>
</message>
<message name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}receiveResponseXMLResponse">
<part name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}receiveResponseXMLResponse" element="tns:{http://developer.intuit.com/}receiveResponseXMLResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="sendRequestXML">
<part name="sendRequestXML" element="tns:sendRequestXML"/>
</message>
<message name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}sendRequestXMLResponse">
<part name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}sendRequestXMLResponse" element="tns:{http://developer.intuit.com/}sendRequestXMLResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="serverVersion">
<part name="serverVersion" element="tns:serverVersion"/>
</message>
<message name="serverVersionResponse">
<part name="serverVersionResponse" element="tns:serverVersionResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="QuickBooksService">
<operation name="authenticate" parameterOrder="authenticate">
<documentation/>
<input name="authenticate" message="tns:authenticate"/>
<output name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}authenticateResponse" message="tns:{http://developer.intuit.com/}authenticateResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="clientVersion" parameterOrder="clientVersion">
<documentation/>
<input name="clientVersion" message="tns:clientVersion"/>
<output name="clientVersionResponse" message="tns:clientVersionResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="closeConnection" parameterOrder="closeConnection">
<documentation/>
<input name="closeConnection" message="tns:closeConnection"/>
<output name="closeConnectionResponse" message="tns:closeConnectionResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="connectionError" parameterOrder="connectionError">
<documentation/>
<input name="connectionError" message="tns:connectionError"/>
<output name="connectionErrorResponse" message="tns:connectionErrorResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="getLastError" parameterOrder="getLastError">
<documentation/>
<input name="getLastError" message="tns:getLastError"/>
<output name="getLastErrorResponse" message="tns:getLastErrorResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="interactiveDone" parameterOrder="interactiveDone">
<documentation/>
<input name="interactiveDone" message="tns:interactiveDone"/>
<output name="interactiveDoneResponse" message="tns:interactiveDoneResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="interactiveRejected" parameterOrder="interactiveRejected">
<documentation/>
<input name="interactiveRejected" message="tns:interactiveRejected"/>
<output name="interactiveRejectedResponse" message="tns:interactiveRejectedResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="interactiveUrl" parameterOrder="interactiveUrl">
<documentation/>
<input name="interactiveUrl" message="tns:interactiveUrl"/>
<output name="interactiveUrlResponse" message="tns:interactiveUrlResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="receiveResponseXML" parameterOrder="receiveResponseXML">
<documentation/>
<input name="receiveResponseXML" message="tns:receiveResponseXML"/>
<output name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}receiveResponseXMLResponse" message="tns:{http://developer.intuit.com/}receiveResponseXMLResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="sendRequestXML" parameterOrder="sendRequestXML">
<documentation/>
<input name="sendRequestXML" message="tns:sendRequestXML"/>
<output name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}sendRequestXMLResponse" message="tns:{http://developer.intuit.com/}sendRequestXMLResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="serverVersion" parameterOrder="serverVersion">
<documentation/>
<input name="serverVersion" message="tns:serverVersion"/>
<output name="serverVersionResponse" message="tns:serverVersionResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<plnk:partnerLinkType name="QuickBooksService">
<plnk:role name="QuickBooksService">
<plnk:portType name="tns:QuickBooksService"/>
</plnk:role>
</plnk:partnerLinkType>
<binding name="QuickBooksService" type="tns:QuickBooksService">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="authenticate">
<soap:operation soapAction="authenticate" style="document"/>
<input name="authenticate">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}authenticateResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="clientVersion">
<soap:operation soapAction="clientVersion" style="document"/>
<input name="clientVersion">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="clientVersionResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="closeConnection">
<soap:operation soapAction="closeConnection" style="document"/>
<input name="closeConnection">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="closeConnectionResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="connectionError">
<soap:operation soapAction="connectionError" style="document"/>
<input name="connectionError">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="connectionErrorResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="getLastError">
<soap:operation soapAction="getLastError" style="document"/>
<input name="getLastError">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="getLastErrorResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="interactiveDone">
<soap:operation soapAction="interactiveDone" style="document"/>
<input name="interactiveDone">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="interactiveDoneResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="interactiveRejected">
<soap:operation soapAction="interactiveRejected" style="document"/>
<input name="interactiveRejected">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="interactiveRejectedResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="interactiveUrl">
<soap:operation soapAction="interactiveUrl" style="document"/>
<input name="interactiveUrl">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="interactiveUrlResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="receiveResponseXML">
<soap:operation soapAction="receiveResponseXML" style="document"/>
<input name="receiveResponseXML">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}receiveResponseXMLResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="sendRequestXML">
<soap:operation soapAction="sendRequestXML" style="document"/>
<input name="sendRequestXML">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="{http://developer.intuit.com/}sendRequestXMLResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="serverVersion">
<soap:operation soapAction="serverVersion" style="document"/>
<input name="serverVersion">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="serverVersionResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="QuickBooksService">
<port name="QuickBooksService" binding="tns:QuickBooksService">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8000/qwc/hello_world/service"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Reading that exception reminds me of how little I miss working with SOAP.

Comment: Can you post your code, and/or the raw SOAP response?

Comment: @consolibyte - I am not able to post code. Its is very huge and i can post only 600 characters here . How to post it ?

Comment: @dan-klasson - If you can help me out to solve this problem it would be great.

Comment: @consolibyte - I edited my post and have attached the code and soap response also. Please have a look and let me know where i am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your web server is closing the connection, when it shouldn't be:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

Are you sure your SOAP service actually works, and that your web server isn't crashing, throwing an error, or closing the connection for no reason?

Another thing I wonder about - you have the Web Connector pointed to your WSDL. Shouldn't it be pointed as the actual web service, not at the WSDL definition?

```
AppURL: http://test:8000/qwc/qwcintegration/service.wsdl
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am new to this SOAP web service. When i copy and paste the App url in browser, i can see the SOAP xml generated properly. What i should provide in App URL?...Please guide me

Comment: What you pasted above is NOT SOAP output. It's WSDL (the SOAP definition/declaration, not the actual SOAP response). If I were you, I would start by finding a SOAP client utility or writing a little test utility to see what you actually get back if you hit the SOAP service with a SOAP request.

Comment: Okie thanks a lot for your response. I need to implement a soap sample service and need to first fix this problem. I really appreciate your suggestion

Comment: You should implement (or download) a SOAP client, and hit the authenticate method, and see what you get back. If you know PHP, we have an example one in our PHP DevKit (http://consolibyte.com/downloads/quickbooks-php-devkit/) that you could use to test: dev/dev_qbwc_tester.php

Comment: Hmm....I donno php programming. But thanks a lot for your help. I will try looking for SOAP client and will see whether it works or not. I may ask some doubts if i get stuck , please help me....